# Check if Large Float is Even or Odd

Tags: python, floating-point, modulo

I have tried using the modulo operator for small floats and it works perfectly fine.
For example: `5 % 2` returns `1`.

But for other large floats that are read as exponential in python it just returns `0` every time even if the number is odd.
Like this:

`295147905179352825855 % 2` returns `0` even though that number is clearly odd.

Is there anything I can do to check large floats without python reading it as exponential?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: When I do `295147905179352825855 % 2` I get `1`. Did you mean `295147905179352825855.0 % 2`? Converting to floating point loses precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said is **not** true. `295147905179352825855 % 2` should work because [Python does arbitrary precision math on **integers**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). There's no floating-point values in your question

OTOH if you use a **float** like `295147905179352825855.0` then it obviously won't work because on most modern platforms [Python uses IEEE-754 binary64 format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) which has only 53 bits of precision and can't store values such as `295147905179352825855.0`. The closest value is `295147905179352825856.0` which is clearly an even number

```
>>> 295147905179352825855 % 2
1
>>> 295147905179352825855.0 % 2
0.0
>>> format(295147905179352825855.0, '.20f')
'295147905179352825856.00000000000000000000'
>>> 295147905179352825856.0 == 295147905179352825855.0
True
```

Comment: When I float the number and print it, this is the result: 2.9514790517935283e+20

Comment: @user14591825 you need to print the full precision to get the actual value:  `format(295147905179352825855.0, '.20f')`

Comment: The source you cite with a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) does not say what your answer says, “Python uses IEEE-754 binary64 format.” It says almost all platforms map Python to IEEE-754 double precision (binary64). “Almost all” is not “all,” and bugs occur when people assume things that are not true. Cited sources should not be misstated.